Will Java compiler optimize the for loop with identical method call inside?
I'm wondering if the Java compiler will optimize the run of the for-loop if there no changes within the for-loop body?
For instance, let's suppose I have the following code:
double res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    res = calculateResValue();
}

Will the compiler shortcut the for-loop into a single calculateResValue() call?
I tried to modify the upper bound of the iteration counter, and I noticed that the time spent within for loop doesn't change proportionally to the boundary increase, i.e. let's suppose I run the loop not for 1000 times but 10000 times. I expect the timing to be increased in 10 times, but it doesn't happen.

The compiler: no. The JIT: perhaps.

Suppose calculateResValue() modifies some external state. Would you want it to be optimized away?

@FedericoklezCulloca not really. Actually, I want it to show the fair time execution. I'm running code as a JUnit unit test, and I think it can use multithreading under the hood, so the real time of the execution could be compromised

My guess is that you are running into Loop Invariant Code Motion. In this case, if a calculation within a loop doesn't change with each iteration, the compiler might move it outside. Have a look at the AI Overview -> type java for loop compiler optimization into Google.

"single calculateResValue() call" - the method must be called that many times, the (javac) compiler does not really know what the method is doing (or it does not analyze it) - it cannot decide if calling once will be a good replacement for all calls (the developer should know that ... ) Also check this question and its answer: How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?
